# override one property of shorthand background property

Tags: css, overriding

Lets say i use the shorhand background property defining multiple properties..eg:

```
.img
{
    background: url('/Content/images/a.png') no-repeat scroll 100% 3px;  
}
```

If i now want to override just the background-postion of the image, should I use the full shorthand notation with the updated position like:

```
.img
{
  background: url('/Content/images/a.png') no-repeat scroll 0 3px;  
}
```

or just override the background-position property like:

```
.img
{
   background-position: 0 3px;  
}
```

If so, what are the issues? Is there a slight performance gain by only overriding the position?

Comment: There are no issues. The issue with overriding the full shorthand is that you may copy and paste wrongly or change some shorthands but forget about others, and things become inconsistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just override the property you need. In fact, this technique is very often used in so-called CSS Sprites:

```
[class*=" icon-"] {
  background: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png") no-repeat scroll 14px;
}

.icon-glass {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.icon-music {
  background-position: -24px 0;
}

.icon-search {
  background-position: -48px 0;
}
```

This approach (you first define a generic full rule, then specify it for each particular class with a shorthand rule) has two obvious advantages:

- it's quite shorter (...than when you repeat full definitions with one property updated), so the CSS file would be smaller
- it's also quite readable (no-one would have to guess whether you've overwritten some prior rule by error).

Comment: thanks raina77ow, just wondering... is there any actual difference between the two ways ? If I've already done it the other way would there be a reason to go and rewrite the css to override just the position?

Comment: @Danield Well, it makes sense if you first define a generic rule for some generic selector, then override some of its parts for _specific_ selector later.